# How to center a div background image that is part of a sprite sheet?

Tags: css, background-image, centering, sprite-sheet

I have a sprite sheet as a background image inside a div.

I would like to only show one sprite as the background image, yet also center the sprite. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your background image is a vertically aligned sprite sheet, you can horizontally center each sprite like this:

```
#center-me {
    background-image: url('images/sprite-sheet.png'); 
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: 50% [y position of sprite];
}
```

If your background image is a horizontally aligned sprite sheet, you can vertically center each sprite like this:

```
#center-me {
    background-image: url('images/sprite-sheet.png'); 
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: [x position of sprite] 50%;
}
```

If your sprite sheet is compact, where there are multiple rows and columns, then these solutions do not apply.